# How to determine whether there are duplicates in a two-dimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have an array like this:

```
Array(
   ["dest0"] => Array(
                  ["id"] => 1,
                  ["name"] => name1   
                 ),    
   ["dest1"] => Array(
                  ["id"] => 2,
                  ["name"] => name2  
                 ),   
  ["dest2"] => Array(
                  ["id"] => 3,
                  ["name"] => name3  
                 ),   
  ["dest3"] => Array(
                  ["id"] => 1,
                  ["name"] => name1   
                 )
);
```

and want to check for duplicate values in it (like here dest0 and dest3 are duplicate), i dont want it to remove them like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/307674/how-to-remove-duplicate-values-from-a-multi-dimensional-array-in-php) , juste check if there's any.

Thanks.

Comment: you mean you need a more efficient way?

Comment: Are there just two dimensions or can there be arbitrary dimensions?

Comment: @Gumbo just two dimensions as in the example .

Comment: Would it suffice just to check for duplicate `id` values?

Comment: thanks for replying, yes that would be enough

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use following code to figure out duplicate (if any):

```
// assuming $arr is your original array
$narr = array();
foreach($arr as $key => $value) {
   $narr[json_encode($value)] = $key;
}
if (count($arr) > count($narr))
   echo "Found duplicate\n";
else
   echo "Found no duplicate\n";
```

Answer (score 1):

Based purely on checking for duplicate id rather than both id and name, but easily modified:

```
$duplicates = array();
array_walk($data, function($testValue, $testKey) use($data, &$duplicates){
                        foreach($data as $key => $value) {
                            if (($value['id'] === $testValue['id']) && ($key !== $testKey))
                                return $duplicates[$testKey] = $testValue;
                        }
                    } );

if (count($duplicates) > 0) {
    echo 'You have the following duplicates:',PHP_EOL;
    var_dump($duplicates);
}
```